# map(long long int,long long int) not working for key=1000 000 000(in range of long long int )

Tags: c++, recursion

Recently I asked a question but about recursion that gives rise to this problem

Note-> count()  The function returns the number of times the key K is present in the map container. It returns 1 if the key is present in the container as the map only contains a unique key. It returns 0 if the key is not present in the map container.
It is passing nearly all the test cases but it is failing `1 000 000 000`
according to long long int range value it should pass this one also but it giving 
some negative value as output ; 
I think this is the problem with container map
Can anyone help me whats wrong with the map?

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    map <long long int,long long int> dp;
    int exchange(long long int n){
        if(n<12)
            return n;
        if(dp.count(n))
            return dp[n];
        return dp[n] = exchange(n/2)+exchange(n/3)+exchange(n/4);
    }
    int main(){
     //   int t;
       // cin>>t;
        while(1){
      //      memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
            long long int n;
            cin>>n;
            cout<<exchange(n)<<endl;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use find instead count ;) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find

Comment: OT hint: never use `<bits/stdc++.h>`, it's non standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this is bad: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`
If you need map, use:

```
#include <map>
```

Then as for the types, if you need something that stored more than 2 billions, use a type you can make sure can hold it (especially for the return type!):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int64_t exchange(std::map& <int64_t, int64_t>, int64_t n){
    if(n<12)
        return n;
    if(dp.count(n))
        return dp[n];
    return dp[n] = exchange(n/2)+exchange(n/3)+exchange(n/4);
}
int main(){
    std::map <int64_t, int64_t> dp;
    while(1){
        int64_t n;
        std::cin>>n;
        std::cout<<exchange(dp, n)<<std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` I guess this is the default header that includes everything in that practice site

Comment: Yes, that's bad :(

Answer (score 6):

The problem is your function `exchange` - it returns `int`, which is a narrower  type than `long long int`.